# Multiple Page Tabs for Multiple Company Pages hosted on the same domain

Tags: facebook, tabs

Is it possible to host multiple tabs for multiple Facebook pages on a single domain?

For example:
Welcome Tabs for:
Company Page 1
Company Page 2
Company Page 3

All hosted in mydomainisawesome.com

(can be: mydomainisawesome.com/company1/welcome.html,  mydomainisawesome.com/company2/welcome.html) etc...

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible.  I host many tab applications from my one domain.  Each of those tabs can be installed on different facebook pages, or even as different tabs on the same page.